# element of list must not move when hovering in primefaces

Tags: java, css, primefaces

I have a list of elements and currently when I hover on the element selected in the list, the element moves slightly, I have thus created a class "remainStill" in the css

```
  <p:selectOneMenu ... class="remainStill">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel=".." />        
     <f:selectItems value="..." />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and in the csss

```
 .remainStill{
     border:0px;
 }
```

but it does not work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "styleClass" instead , "class" alone does not work